# Python Regex Bullet Point and multiple line match

Tags: python, regex

Wanting to match something that's between two words or phrases, that has a bullet point inside of it, is on multiple lines in python and works for every variation of the words between the beginning and end. Don't know the identifier used for bullet points or the identifiers to match everything including line breaks. For example trying to match:

```
Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World
```

in

```
 hello_big_old_world = "qweqrqr  Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World fdsfdas"
```

Where this string is over multiple lines. I know its probably not in the ball park, but here's what I have so far and obviously it isn't working.

```
Answer = re.findall("(?<=qweqrqr)(.*\n?)/s(?=fdsfdas)"), hello_big_old_world)
print(Answer)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'qweqrqr([^\u2022]*\u2022.*?)fdsfdas', hello_big_old_world, re.S)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match the string from `qweqrqr` to `fdsfdas` with at least 1 bullet point using

```
hello_big_old_world = "qweqrqr  Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World fdsfdas"
print(re.findall(r'qweqrqr([^\u2022]*\u2022.*?)fdsfdas', hello_big_old_world, re.S))
```

See the [Python 3 demo](https://ideone.com/sey8Ty).

Note that you may use `•` instead of the Unicode char representation and also strip the whitespaces from the captured text if you add `\s*` (=0+ whitespace chars) on both ends of the parenthetical group:

```
re.findall(r'qweqrqr\s*([^•]*•.*?)\s*fdsfdas', hello_big_old_world, re.S)
```

It should [work in both Python 3](https://ideone.com/giEejp) and Python 2.

**Details**

- `qweqrqr` - matches the right delimiter
- `([^\u2022]*\u2022.*?)` / `([^•]*•.*?)` - captures into Group 1 (the string returned with `re.findall`)

  - `[^\u2022]*` / `[^•]*` - any chars other than the bullet point
  - `\u2022` / `•` - the bullet point
  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars (including a newline due to the `re.S` (=`re.DOTALL`) flag) as few as possible (due to the lazy quantifier `*?`)
- `fdsfdas` - matches the left delimiter

Answer (score 1):

To match all characters including newlines, you still use the `.` character, but pass `flags=re.DOTALL` to functions such as `re.findall`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `regex` with slight changes:

- `/s` should be `\s`.
- use `re.DOTALL` to match cases where you have newlines in-between.

Working **code**:

```
import re

hello_big_old_world = 'qweqrqr  Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World fdsfdas'

Answer = re.findall("(?<=qweqrqr)(.*\n?)\s(?=fdsfdas)", hello_big_old_world, re.DOTALL)
print(Answer)

# [' Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World Hello • World']
```